# Как в python использовать коллекцию переменных для запуска тестов?

Tags: python, переменные, pytest

Надо запустить одну коллекцию на разных наборах данных

Параметры одинаковые (логин, пароль, url и т.д.), но с разными значениями.
Подскажите пожалуйста как лучше сделать.

Нашла, что можно сделать 2 ini файла и  примерно так в каждом:

```
[pytest]
env =
    base_url = 'https://url.ru'
    default_user = {'username': 'login@gmail.com', 'password': 'password'}
    default_org_oguid = '123456'
    и т.д.
```

И при запуске тестов использовать конкретный файл:

```
pytest -c pytest.ini
```

Но как в таком случае указать эти base_url и т.д. в тестах?
Или можно как то по другому сделать?

Comment: В смысле как указать? Считываете значения в переменные и используете их.

Comment: Очень прошу строчку примера. base_url = os.environ["base_url"] не принимает. Как в файл ".py" , который внутри не одной папки проекта указать переменную из файла .ini, который указан в корне проекта

Comment: Использовать переменные окружения это слегка оверкил :) Посмотрите на модуль ConfigParser, он как раз для похожих задач.

Comment: Спасибо! попробую

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/configparser.html